# In Moon APNS, what is the logic behind fetching valid tokens, in GetFeedBack method?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I have been trying to figure out list of valid tokens for my Apple app using MoonAPNS library.
While using GetFeedBack() the count of received tokens is varying drastically after few minutes.
In first attempt it was around 8000.
Then it was 0
in third attempt it was 1
& again it was 0.

I am using it with valid production certificate. & Have successfully pushed notifications using same certificate to sampled devices.

I do not understand the logic of the code & on what basis it is providing received tokens.
The code downloaded from Moon APNS  is as below.

```
public List<Feedback> GetFeedBack()
{
  try
  {
    var feedbacks = new List<Feedback>();
    Logger.Info("Connecting to feedback service.");

    if (!_conected)
        Connect(_feedbackHost, FeedbackPort, _certificates);

    if (_conected)
    {
        //Set up
        byte[] buffer = new byte[38];
        int recd = 0;
        DateTime minTimestamp = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

        //Get the first feedback
        recd = _apnsStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Logger.Info("Feedback response received.");

        if (recd == 0)
            Logger.Info("Feedback response is empty.");

        //Continue while we have results and are not disposing
        while (recd > 0)
        {
            Logger.Info("processing feedback response");
            var fb = new Feedback();

            //Get our seconds since 1970 ?
            byte[] bSeconds = new byte[4];
            byte[] bDeviceToken = new byte[32];

            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, bSeconds, 0, 4);

            //Check endianness
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(bSeconds);

            int tSeconds = BitConverter.ToInt32(bSeconds, 0);

            //Add seconds since 1970 to that date, in UTC and then get it locally
            fb.Timestamp = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(tSeconds).ToLocalTime();


            //Now copy out the device token
            Array.Copy(buffer, 6, bDeviceToken, 0, 32);

            fb.DeviceToken = BitConverter.ToString(bDeviceToken).Replace("-", "").ToLower().Trim();

            //Make sure we have a good feedback tuple
            if (fb.DeviceToken.Length == 64 && fb.Timestamp > minTimestamp)
            {
                //Raise event
                //this.Feedback(this, fb);
                feedbacks.Add(fb);
            }

            //Clear our array to reuse it
            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            //Read the next feedback
            recd = _apnsStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        //clode the connection here !
        Disconnect();
        if (feedbacks.Count > 0)
            Logger.Info("Total {0} feedbacks received.", feedbacks.Count);
        return feedbacks;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logger.Error("Error occurred on receiving feed back. - " + ex.Message);
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I have not used Moon APNS, but the way the APNS Feedback Service works is every time you call it, it will return inactive tokens since the last time you called the feedback service.  And that explains the pattern you are seeing here.

Comment: It means, if I run feedback once, get list of Invalid Tokens but does not take any action (in my DB) to disable the tokens, I loose the information of invalid tokens forever & next time onwards feedback service will treat the token as valid. Is there any time limit after which apple will again give a feedback of all those invalid tokens? Also, I assume if I remove app from device & reinstall I will get new unique token next time, which will not match my previous token (this will help me using app when previous token is disabled in my DB)

Comment: Once a token has been reported by APNS as invalid, subsequent calls to the Feedback service will not return that token.  If you try to send a push notification to that token, APNS will reject your request.  Also, APNS does not guarantee a new push token will be generated if the app is reinstalled.  From my own experience, the same push token can be used after uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Does that mean after getting feedback once, when the token has now bean treated as valid, if I send a push notification & apple rejects the token, in next cycle of feedback (after pushing notification) the token will be shown as invalid, again? Jason, Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  But there are a few ways a token can be invalidated: 1) if the user uninstalls the app and 2) the user disables push notification for the app (via Settings).  So a push token doesn't automatically become valid after you call the Feedback Service.  Most of the time, once a token becomes invalid, it stays invalid.

Comment: Let me explain my question with ex. I execute APNS FB(Feedback) and I get T1&T2 as invalid tokens, but I dont save them. Next time if I execute FB, the service will not provide T1&T2 as invalid (being these are reported last time).It may report an another token T3 which was uninstalled after my 1st execution.Is there any way to get the earlier(T1&T2) as well by executing FB. ex if I run Push(not FB),now, T1 T2 & T3 will be rejected,if I run FB again will get all these as invalid? Summary: I mean every time only incremental info of invalid tokens is provided by FB can I get consolidated list?

Comment: There is no way to get a consolidated list of invalid tokens directly from APNS.   Services like Urban Airship acts as an intermediary and does what you are asking.